# Quantum Random Oracle Model

Tags: hash, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography

Let $\mathcal{H} : \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{1,\cdots,n\}$ be a hash function.

I believe that in the Random Oracle model, the probability that an adversary $A$ can find a message $M$ such that $\mathcal{H}(M) \leq k$ is at most $(q+1) \frac{k}{n}$, where $q$ is the number of queries $A$ makes to $\mathcal{H}$.

What happens for a quantum adversary $B$, which can query $\mathcal{H}$ in superposition? I suspect that the probability that $B$ produces a message $M$ such that $\mathcal{H}(M)\leq k$ is bounded by $c q^2 \frac{k}{n}$, where $q$ i the number of quantum queries that $B$ makes to $\mathcal{H}$ and $c$ some constant.

I suspect this because this can be done with Grover's algorithm and I heard that Grover's Algorithm is optimal in some setting.

Is this true? What values of $c$ would work? How would you prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the success probability of a $q$-query quantum adversary is $\Theta(\frac{k(q+1)^2}{n})$. You can find a proof of the upper and lower bound in [this paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1256.pdf).

The upper bound uses similar tools as for the optimality of Grover. The tricky part is that the proof of optimality for Grover's algorithm is given for the worst-case but I guess you and people in crypto in general are mainly interested in the average case complexity. So you need a more advanced toolkit.

The lower bound is more or less applying Grover and analysing its success probability for the average case.